# Read specific column in csv file using Pycharm

Tags: python

```
import csv
with open("bbkp.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimeter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {",".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{row[0]}latitude {row[1]}longitude {row[2]}.')
            line_count += 1
        print(f'Result {line_count}lines.')
    for lines in csv_reader:
        print(lines[1])
```

the error show

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "E:/PSM/source code/gile.py", line 8, in 
>      csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimeter=',')
>   TypeError: 'delimeter' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: You misspelled `delimiter`.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Can I ask something? Before this I'm using dummy data that contains several points <10 points to find min and max boundary area and it works. But right now I'm using >1000 points of coordinates latitude and longitude. It is possible I can define from that coordinate to find min and max boundary from coordinates points? Thank You in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try 
`csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)` 
the delimiter of csv reader is ',' by default so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask something? Before this I'm using dummy data that contains several points <10 points to find min and max boundary area and it works. But right now I'm using >1000 points of coordinates latitude and longitude. It is possible I can define from that coordinate to find min and max boundary from coordinates points? Thank You in advanced

Comment: You welcome, vote up, or marking the question as answered will be appreciated. about the coordinates, I'm not so familiar with this topic but if I will see some code I may be able to understand something.